# SBT Native Packager: Build the same package with different configs

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm trying to create builds with deferent configuration files with help of SBT Native Packager. I have a standard project layout for Scala projects:

```
my-app
--/project
----/build.properties
----/plugins.sbt
--/src
----/main
------/java
------/resources
------/scala
----/test
------/java
------/resources
------/scala
build.sbt
```

So I added the sbt-native-packager plugin to my project and decided to repeat the [SBT submodule approach](http://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/package_configuration.html#sbt-sub-modules).

That's how my build.sbt file looks like:

```
import sbt.Keys._

scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.12.1"

lazy val app = project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "backend",
    version := "1.0",
    libraryDependencies ++= {
      val akkaVersion = "2.4.17"
      val akkaHttpVersion = "10.0.5"
      Seq(
        "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaVersion,
        "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % akkaHttpVersion,
        "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json" % akkaHttpVersion
      )
    }
  )

lazy val devPackage = project
  .in(file("build/dev"))
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
  .settings(
    name := "backend-dev",
    resourceDirectory in Compile := (resourceDirectory in (app, Compile)).value,
    mappings in Universal += {
      ((resourceDirectory in Compile).value / "dev.conf") -> "conf/application.conf"
    }
  )
  .dependsOn(app)
```

And here are application.conf and dev.conf (both are located in src/main/resources:

```
akka {
  loglevel = INFO
  stdout-loglevel = INFO
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  default-dispatcher {
    fork-join-executor {
      parallelism-min = 8
    }
  }
  http {
    server {
      server-header = "PinPoint REST API"
      request-timeout = "10.seconds"
    }
  }
}

database {
  dataSourceClass = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
  properties = {
    databaseName = "pg_db"
    user = "alex"
    password = ""
  }
  numThreads = 10
}
```

and

```
include "application"

database {
  dataSourceClass = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
  properties = {
    databaseName = "pg_db_dev"
    user = "alex"
    password = "secure_password"
  }
  numThreads = 10
}
```

After I run `sbt devPackage/stage` in the terminal I get new directory "build" in the root folder of the project. But inside of the:
build/dev/target/universal/stage/
There is no "bin" folder with runable sh script.

So how to fix this?

Comment: If you have different main classes then you need to specify one of them like mainClass in Compile := Some("foo.bar.Main"). See http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/java_app/ for more details.

Comment: @kardapoltsev I have only one main class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Universal Packager won't create startup scripts if the `mainClass` setting isn't set - and `sbt` won't auto-set it for you from jar files in your classpath.

All you need to do is add the setting to your `devPackage` project:

```
lazy val devPackage = project
  .in(file("build/dev"))
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
  .settings(
    name := "backend-dev",
    resourceDirectory in Compile := (resourceDirectory in (app, Compile)).value,
    // TODO: Use real classname here:
    mainClass in Compile := Some("my.main.ClassName"),
    mappings in Universal += {
      ((resourceDirectory in Compile).value / "dev.conf") -> "conf/application.conf"
    }
  )
  .dependsOn(app)
```